# Need help storing/retrieveing data

Tags: java, data-structures

A user has an ArrayList of numbers.  Those numbers correspond to the applications that they have access to.  Certain applications have different entitlement numbers(ie- 3, 72, etc.).  What I want to do is store this data in a map so that when the user logs in, they can input their numbers into the Map and quickly get the applications that they are entitled to.  However, some applications require 2 to 3 entitlement numbers.  For example, one entry could be: ("101 and 234", "Application 1").  I was wondering if there was an ideal way of retrieving all of the values from the map that that users entitlement numbers satisfies.

How I currently have it, the program compares the users data to each application and confirms or denies access.  This seems inefficient.  Any help us greatly appreciated!

Note: I am reading the applications and their numbers in from an XML, so I can store them as I wish.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with example? I don't think I get all the cases down.

Comment: Sorry about that, every time a user logs in, I want to compare their list of strings with a map of string that corresponds to an application. A users entitlement numbers may look something like: {"1", "2", "3", "5"}. I want to compare this list of strings with all of the application number.  Most applications have 1 entitlement number. So, I input 1 into the map, and I am returned "Application 3".  That is fine. But some applications require entitlement numbers "2 and 3". I am having trouble doing it in O(1) time when the numbers are compound. I was thinking about having one map output another

Comment: Is the case: "1" --> "App1", "2" --> "App2", {"1", "2"} --> "AppTwoEntitlement" possible? And if you give {"1", "2"}, will it returns all 3 apps?

Comment: Correct.  Currently, it goes through every application, and compares that applications number to the users.  This is clearly inefficient for 300+ applications if the user only has something like 10 number.  My goal is to input each entitlement number into the map of all applications and return a list of applications that he/she has access to.

Comment: Is the entitlement plainly number, or can it be arbitrary string? (Asking for now and the future also).

Comment: Arbitrary string.  Mostly number: "2" but could be letters as well: "this.that.access.string".  Essentially, have to treat it as a string entirely.

Comment: How many of the applications require multiple entitlements?

Comment: Not a lot. I would say about 20 or so.

Answer (score 0):

If there are large numbers of numbers required per application, the best approach is to use set intersection. If the numbers are contiguous or at least dense, you can optimize this into a bitset. For only one or two numbers though, I'd recommend just testing each number individually, since it's likely to be faster than full set operations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

- Define a class for each application (let's call it `App`). The class contains the name of the application, and a (sorted) List/array of entitlements.
- Use Map to map from String to `App`: `Map<String, App>` for all single entitlement apps (you can use `HashMap` or `TreeMap` - your choice). If there are multiple apps that only need one and the same entitlement, consider `Map<String, List<App>>`. Exclude the apps that need multiple entitlements from the Map, and store them in a separate List/array instead.
- When you are given a list of entitlements to retrieve apps, loop through the list and just grab everything that the `Map` maps the String to. For those that needs multiple entitlements, just check individually (you can speed up the checking a bit by sorting the list of entitlements given, and storing the entitlements to each `App` in sorted order - but it may not even matter since the size is small).

The solution reduces the time complexity for the operation. However, a few hundred apps times the number of entitlements of around 10 is quite small in my opinion, unless you call this many times. And it's better to time your original approach and this approach to compare - since the overhead might shadows any improvement in time.

A bit of further improvement (or not) is:

- Use `Map<String, List<App>>` and include even apps that need multiple entitlements (those app will be mapped to by many entitlements).
- When we search for app, we will use a `Map<App, Integer>` to keep track of how many entitlements that we have confirmed for multiple entitlement apps. So the flow will be like:

  ```
  new mapAppInteger
  foreach entitlement in inputListOfEntitlement
      listOfApps = mapStringAppList.get(entitlement)

      if listOfApps found
          for each app in listOfApps
              if app needs singleEntitlement
                  put app in output list
              else // needs multiple
                  if app is in mapAppInteger
                      map app --> count + 1
                      if mapAppInteger.get(app) == app.numberOfRequiredEntitlement
                          put app in output list
                          remove app from mapAppInteger
                  else // not in mapAppInteger
                      map app --> 1
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will compare the two!